# Firebase Phone Authentication Rest API

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-api

I want to verify user phone number with Firebase. I want Firebase phone authentication API.

cURL request I tried:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendVerificationCode?key=AIzaSyAqQlhpjv86*********-*************',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "phoneNumber": "+9199*******0"
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: key=AIzaSyAqQlhpjv86*********-*************',
    'x-goog-client-id: ************-******************************ho.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Response

> { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER", "errors": [ { "message": "TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER", "domain": "global", "reason": "invalid" } ] } }

And when I call the cURL request after an hour still same response.